# Eloquent Javascript (4.4 Deep Comparison)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the following question:

Write a function, deepEqual, that takes two values and returns true only if they are the same value or are objects with the same properties whose values are also equal when compared with a recursive call to deepEqual.

To find out whether to compare two things by identity (use the === operator for that) or by looking at their properties, you can use the typeof operator. If it produces "object" for both values, you should do a deep comparison. But you have to take one silly exception into account: by a historical accident, typeof null also produces "object".

My code is as follows:

```
var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 55}));

function deepEqual(obj1, obj2){
  if (obj1===obj2) {return true;}
  else if(obj1===null || obj2=== null ){return false;}
  else{
    if(typeof(obj1)==="object" || typeof(obj2)==="object"){
      for ( var key in obj1 ) {
          //console.log(obj1[key]);
          //console.log(obj2[key]);
          //console.log("compares:"+obj1[key]+" with "+obj2[key]);
          return JSON.stringify(obj1[key])===JSON.stringify(obj2[key]);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

I should be getting false(because of differing values 2 and 55), but I am getting true. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Your comparison only runs for the first iteration as you're `return`ing immediately.

Comment: What is a good way to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you can find some answers [here](https://github.com/substack/node-deep-equal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get true because, you return value right after comparison of the first key in the object.

Did a small change in you code:

```js
var obj = {
  here: {
    is: "an"
  },
  object: 2
};
console.log("falsy test: " + deepEqual(obj, {
  here: {
    is: "an"
  },
  object: 55
}));

console.log("truthy test: " + deepEqual(obj, {
  here: {
    is: "an"
  },
  object: 2
}));

function deepEqual(obj1, obj2) {
  var result = false;
  if (obj1 === obj2) {
    return true;
  } else if (obj1 === null || obj2 === null) {
    return false;
  } else {
    if (typeof(obj1) === "object" || typeof(obj2) === "object") {
      for (var key in obj1) {
        //console.log(obj1[key]);
        //console.log(obj2[key]);
        //console.log("compares:"+obj1[key]+" with "+obj2[key]);
        if (JSON.stringify(obj1[key]) === JSON.stringify(obj2[key])) {
          result = true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }

      };
      //return result after all the values in object are compared.
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```